# jQuery function to use href instead of input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am currently using an input value in a form to dynamically kick off a function to search an array for zip codes and display like this and it works great:

```
$('input[name=zip]').keyup(function() {
```

I'd like to make the button element be used instead so that when you keydown it performs the same function.

The "button" is a HREF element like this:

```
<a class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-27" href="#"><span class="label">Calculate Quote</span></a>
```

I tried to alter the input element like this to use an `a` and also a `href` and switched the `name=` to a `id=` to no avail.  Is it possible to do this?

```
  $('a[id=lp-pom-button-27]').keyup(function() {
```

Comment: Don't you want to bind a `.click` event to an `<a>` tag, not `.keyup`?  P.S. IDs are unique, so you can just do `$('#lp-pom-button-27')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use `mouseup` instead?

```
$('a[id=lp-pom-button-27]').mouseup(function () {
```

The element `<a>` can receive only mouse events and not keyboard events.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$('a[id=lp-pom-button-27]').click(function() {
```

I do not see how you can `keyup` on a button, `click` event seems a better option for me.